# How to suspend updating a currently editing cell in the bounded DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to the collection, which is changed frequently (not collection itself, but properties of the objects). When I start editing a cell, it quickly replaces with new value, which came from PropertyChanged event. Is there anyway to "suspend" currently editing cell from updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by adding a `BindingSource`.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = yourdatasource;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Within the CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events of the datagridview you can then change the binding source's RaiseListChangedEvents property:

```
void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource1.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
}

void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource1.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
}
```

I tested this with a background worker with a sleep inside it started by a button, and an update to the bound list after that. I pressed the button then edited a cell, and after the timer expired, my changes to the cell still held.

When I didn't begin editing the cell changes to the list were changed.

---

One thing to note is that this is for the whole binding source, not a particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the bound property to be updated only when you get out of the field (or when the field is updated from the code), then I think you should use DataBindingMode.OnValidated instead of DataBindingMode.OnPropertyChanged at the moment you create your binding.

Comment: DataGridView does not have DataBindingmode property. How can I change this mode?

Comment: The myDataGridView.DataBindings.Add has DataSourceUpdateMode typed argument.